# Sqlalchemy foreign key to a subset of polymorphic classes

Tags: python, database-design, orm, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations

I am using sqlalchemy to create a structure that resembles a graph, so that there are several types of nodes and links joining them.  The nodes are defined like this:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Unicode)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

class InputNode(Node):
    __tablename__ = 'inputnode'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'input'}

class ThruNode(Node):
    __tablename__ = 'thrunode'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'thru'}

class OutputNode(Node):
    __tablename__ = 'outputnode'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'output'}
```

Now I want to create a `Link` table which would looks something like this:

```
class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    input = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id', where='type IN ("input", "thru")'))
    output = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id', where='type IN ("thru", "output")'))
```

The bit I'm struggling with is how to do the `where` part of it, since as I've written it is not valid in sqlalchemy.  I had though of using a `CheckConstraint` or a `ForeignKeyConstraint`, but I can't see how either of them could actually be used to do this.

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: @jpmorin No.  Fortunately for me this project has now been sidelined, so I don't need to worry.  However, I think that the real solution would have been to use a nosql database like neo4j.  I'd still like to know how it can be done in sqlalchemy though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tryed it nor am I an expert of this, but shouldn't this work?

```
class Link(Base):
__tablename__ = 'link'
input = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thrunode.id'))
output = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('outputnode.id'))
```

First I had another idea that maybe you could have used different names for the ids and than use those, kind of like:
instead of:

`class InputNode(Node):
    __tablename__ = 'inputnode'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'input'}`

this:

`class ThruNode(Node):
    [...]
    thrunode_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    [...]`

and then:

```
class Link(Base):
__tablename__ = 'link'
input = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.thrunode_id'))
output = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.outputnode_id'))
```

I got the idea from here [sqlalchemy docs: declarative.html#joined-table-inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#joined-table-inheritance)

Comment: That restricts input to a ThruNode, which is not what I want. I'm trying to say it can be either a ThruNode or an InputNode.

Comment: Another possibility could be to make thru node inherit from node, and then let input node and output node inherit from thrunode. But maybe I should just stop trying to answer questions I don't really know about...